# Rename attachment file in InfoPath without code

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I want to rename the file attached in InfoPath form with my random generated number.I don't want to write custom code

Is there any possibility to do it using Action and Rules.

Can anyone suggest me the possible ways to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To rename an InfoPath attachment, you first have to **decode** it, change its file name, **encode** it again, and then save it. So probably not possible to change name without using custom code.

Comment: do you have any code snippet or link?

Answer (score 2):

To rename an InfoPath attachment, you first have to **decode** it, change its file name, **encode** it again, and then save it. So probably not possible to change name without using custom code.

From these reference from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a67b7caa-d366-4678-a522-cd9a4587d186/assign-the-attachment-file-name-to-a-text-box-field-in-infopath-2013?forum=sharepointcustomization) and [bizsupport](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/03/programmatically-rename-infopath-file-attachment/), you can get the information. And from this [article](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/04/top-10-questions-infopath-file-attachments/) you can get more important information about InfoPath attachments.

Hope this will help.

Comment: i tried this code http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/03/programmatically-rename-infopath-file-attachment/ but it is giving me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error

Comment: You are getting this error because of throwing a `NullReferenceException` in run time. Can you please check from where you are getting this error specifically? And check if you used the class files properly. You can try this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/892730), it has some more details on the same process which you are following from **bizsupport**. This may help.

Comment: can we add InfoPath having custom code in office365?

Comment: Probably you can't.